# how to close aspx page on button click after saving data in database

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one asp.net application having single page (x.aspx). It is few textbox, radio buttion etc and a button. On button click, I need to first save data into database with calling one web api and then close the page. Please note that this page is not popup. If I put RegisterOnSubmitStatement on page_load it closes the page but then button click does not fire. I tried RegisterclientScriptBlock, RegisterStartupScript but none of them works.

Please suggest how to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

after saveing date

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
//Save data here and after that execut script
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but the issue is I can do that only in postback once user enter data and submit. If i put RegisterOnSubmit in if (IsPostBack) it does not close and if I put outside that, it will close before save.

Comment: in simple save a value in javascript function and update the value in code after save date and in jaavascript  function close the window if the condition is true

Comment: Could you please elaborate this further? Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

You can register the closing code with `RegisterStartupScript` in the button click event handler. That code will be executed on the client side after the processing has been done on the server:

```
protected void btnSaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save data to database
    ...

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ClosePage", "window.close();", true);
}
```

**Method 2**

You can try closing the page after a delay:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="setTimeout(function () { window.close(); }, 1000);" ... />
```

In this example, the page will close after one second (1000 ms). You can adjust the delay to fit your needs.

**Method 3**

This method makes sure that the window is not closed before the data saving method has finished.

On the button click that triggers the saving procedure, start an interval timer to send a periodic AJAX request to the server. When the response from the server confirms that the data has been saved, close the window.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveData" runat="server" OnClientClick="checkIsDataSaved()" ... />

function checkIsDataSaved() {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $.get('', 'isDataSaved', function (data) {
            if (data == "done") {
                // The data has been saved, close the window
                clearInterval(interval);
                window.close();
            }
        });
    }, 1000);  // Every 1000 ms
}
```

In code-behind, set a flag in a Session variable after saving the data:

```
protected void SaveDataMethod()
{
    // Save to database
    ...

    Session["DataSaved"] = true;
    Response.End();
}
```

In `Page_Load`, receive the AJAX request and send the result:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString.ToString() == "isDataSaved")
    {
        bool isDataSaved = Session["DataSaved"] != null && (bool)Session["DataSaved"];
        Session["DataSaved"] = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Write(isDataSaved ? "done" : "saving");
        Response.End();
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not close the page. looks like doing everything with javascript/jQuery is the only solution

Comment: dont you think it would be risky approach as in some cases, api call take more time and before data saved in db, it will close out the page?

Comment: I added another suggestion. I tested it successfully with an artificially long "saving" procedure on the server.